# Publicar proyecto MVC con visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017

Buen día estimados, tengo una aplicación web la cual quiero publicar, estuve viendo páginas y tutoriales donde las publican con la opción **file system** pero cuando lo hago me pone una advertencia que esa opción no soporta la base de datos, la aplicación la tengo conectada a una base de datos en sql server por medio de entity framework, si alguien tiene una guía, o método de cómo publicar mi aplicación sería de gran ayuda.

El proyecto se va publicar EN IIS

Comment: Si la necesitas publicar en un hostin , o quieres publciarlo en una web de foro? muchos hosting no sorportan aspx tienes que rentar uno que tenga soporte de ISS asi podras publicar tu web

Comment: Se va publicar en IIS

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/ lectura recomendada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tenes que configurar la string de conexion a la base de datos en el archivo Web.config de tu proyecto, y luego hacer la exportacion como te dicen los tutoriales, sino, la otra, es publicarlo en azure directamente y te ahorra todos los pasos, pero es caro